# Grant a login of Sql server authentication the same permission of a Windows group login with Windows authentication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Update:**
I am trying to make it easier for the login to have the permissions on multiple databases.

I already have a Windows group login with Windows authentication. The Windows users in the group can access multiple databases on a server.

Now I need to create an Sql server login and I want it have the same permission of the Windows group login (so it will have the permissions on mulitple database). Is it possible to do it without grant all the permissions to the SQL server separately?

I tried to create a credential for the Windows group login and add the credential to the SQL login but it doesn't work.

```
create credential WinGroupLogin with identity = 'MyServer\WinGroupLogin'
ALTER LOGIN [sql_login] ADD CREDENTIAL [WinGroupLogin]
```

Answer (score 0):

always attempt to set permission on database roles or server roles. Create or select a role, set your desired permission ,add all login you want to have same permission to the role.